# Spring integration: no such method exception for custom inbound channel adapter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I am trying to invoke `processMessage` method from my `As2MessageHandler` class as my entry point into spring integration using a custom inbound-channel-adapter. But I keep getting this error saying it can't find the method when it is clearly in the class:

`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'as2.source': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no such method 'processMessage' is available on class com.as2example.myexample.handler.As2MessageHandler`

as2MessageHandler class:

```
@Component
public class As2MessageHandler extends AbstractProcessorModule implements IProcessorStorageModule {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(As2MessageHandler.class);


    @Override
    public boolean canHandle(@Nonnull String s, @Nonnull IMessage iMessage, @Nullable Map<String, Object> map) {
        LOGGER.info(" Handle Info:" + s);

        return s.equals(DO_STORE);
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(@Nonnull String s, @Nonnull IMessage iMessage, @Nullable Map<String, Object> map) throws AS2Exception {

        LOGGER.info("----- AS2 MESSAGE RECEIVED !!! ------");

        LOGGER.info(iMessage.getContentType());
        LOGGER.info(iMessage.getContentDisposition());
        LOGGER.info(iMessage.getAsString());

        processMessage(iMessage);

    }

    public String processMessage(IMessage message) {

        LOGGER.info("BEGIN PROCESSING MESSAGE");

        return message.getAsString();
    }


}
```

integration.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
         https://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd">



    <int:channel id="as2MessageChannel">
        <int:interceptors>
            <int:wire-tap channel="logger"/>
        </int:interceptors>
    </int:channel>

    <int:logging-channel-adapter id="logger" level="DEBUG"/>


    <int:inbound-channel-adapter id="as2" ref="as2MessageHandler" method="processMessage" channel="as2MessageChannel">

    </int:inbound-channel-adapter>



    <int:service-activator input-channel="as2MessageChannel" ref="orderServiceImpl" auto-startup="true"/>



</beans>
```

MyApplication class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("classpath:/integration/integration.xml")
public class MyApplication implements ServletContextListener {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }


    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed (final ServletContextEvent sce)
    {
        ServletConfig.shutDown ();
        AS2WebAppListener.staticDestroy ();
    }

}
```

Can anyone provide insight into why spring integration is not recognizing the processMethod from the As2MessageHandler class? I've tried changing the method to use messagebuilder and return a Message type but that wasn't the issue. Now I'm thinking it has to be something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is correct. It might mislead a little bit since the signature of the method is wrong, not its presence. So, since an inbound channel adapter is a beginning of the flow, there really cannot be any input to the method to produce data for messages. Therefore it is not clear what is your expectation with that `IMessage` as an input for the method.

It is not clear what is your design, but the POJO method in the `<int:inbound-channel-adapter>` is invoked by the poller as a source of data for the message. In other words the POJO method as a source must not have arguments - only return. That's why that exception is thrown.

I don't see anything in your `As2MessageHandler` which could server as a source for messages in the inbound channel adapter. This one looks more like a service activator. Please, revise your design in favor of something else what really may be used as a source of data in that AS2 protocol.